# Where is the cgroup log

Tags: linux, resources, cgroups

I try to find the cgroup start/stop log but I cannot find it. 
I find it not in /var/log/messages and dmesg
Is there any way to trace the cgroup service start/stop behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there really isn't a log as cgroups are essentially mount options. To get more details about an issue you're having you'll need to manually mount the cgroup using `mount`: `mount -t cgroup ...`.

The [official kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt) have more information as well.

You can also `strace -f -s 1000` your manual mount of a cgroup to see if that has any pertinent information.